# Symmetric template's arguments

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

Suppose we have some converting routine class. If we can convert from `T` class to `U`, we automatically can convert vise versa.

I represent it with a template class and some specializations:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class Convert;

template <>
class Convert<A,B> {
    static int param() { return 42; }
}

template <>
class Convert<B,A> {
    static int param() { return -Convert<A,B>::param(); }
}
```

This works good, but when we need to add new type for routine, we must add 2 specializiations. 
Can we reduce that number to 1 by defining some general reverse template class like this:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
class Convert {
    static int param() { return -Convert<U,T>::param(); }
}
```

which could be work if we already have Convert specialization?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can add the conversion to the class definition, and make another specialization for two equal parameters. Then you have to specify only n*(n-1)/2 classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the suggestion in my comment elaborated:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<type_traits>

struct A{};
struct B{};
struct C{};

template <typename ... Args>
struct Convert;

template <typename T>
struct Convert<T,T> {
    static int param() { return 0; }
};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct Convert<T,U> {
    static decltype(-Convert<U,T>::param()) param() { return -Convert<U,T>::param(); }
};

template <>
struct Convert<A,B> {
    static int param() { return 42; }
};

template <>
struct Convert<A,C> {
    static int param() { return 43; }
};

template <>
struct Convert<B,C> {
    static int param() { return 44; }
};

int main()
{
    std::cout<<Convert<A,B>::param()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<Convert<B,A>::param()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<Convert<A,C>::param()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<Convert<C,A>::param()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<Convert<B,C>::param()<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<Convert<C,B>::param()<<std::endl;

    Convert<int,double>::param();
}
```

---

The idea is to once give a general declaration, and then specify first the case where the template arguments are equal (that should give zero) as well as the case where they are different, in which the converted parameter is returned.

Next, for `n` classes, you need to give the specializations for all the `n*(n-1)/2` `Convert` classes. (in case it is needed, this could further be simplified by derivation, for example).

Comment: For same `T` we possibly need a specialization with 2 arguments.  `struct Convert<T,T>`. Otherwise this `Convert<A,A>::param()` could not compile.

Comment: Alas, this doesn't work so well. Try to add `cout << Convert<int,double>::param()` and see for yourself.

Comment: There are no specializations for `int` or `double`, so this naturally won't work. One could add some `static_assert` to allow only for certain classes.

Comment: That's the point. If the user did not specialize for these types it should not compile. But it does, and crashes at run time.

Comment: That's correct. I've added some type checking via `static_assert` to the code.

Comment: You've just made your system closed to extension. The user cannot add anything without modifying existing code. This is a complete anti-solution.

Comment: I'm always open to constructive suggestions, so please bring one. Here is another: derive all your classes from `struct SymmetricConversionAllowed{};`, then replace `std::is_same` by `std::is_base_of`. This doesn't work for native types, however. Looking forward to your approach.

Comment: Yes, that's better. For others: in the `Convert<T,U>` class template you replaced the type `int` by `decltype(-Convert<U,T>::param())` and thus enforce the compiler to instantiate the type at compile time. I'll edit it in.

Comment: But what about `Convert<int,int>::param();` in your solution? It returns `0` though it should give a compile-time error.

Comment: @davidhigh there is a specialization for `<T,T>` that handles such cases. It's identical to one in your code and serves the exact same purpose. If for some esoteric reason you don't want a type to be trivially convertible to itself, remove it.